# How to run 3 kettle scripts one after other

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am new with kettle so I am going to run the  3 kettle script 1.ktr,2.ktr,3.ktr one after other.

Can someone give me the idea how to achive this using kettle steps.

Answer (score 2):

usually, you organize your kettle transformations within kettle `jobs` (.kjb). In those jobs you can have transformations being processed one after the other. You can also include `jobs` within `jobs` to further organize your ETL process. If you execute your jobs and transformations from the command line, please be aware that you execute transformations with the tool `kitchen`, transformations with `pan`. You can create jobs like you can create transformations, with `spoon`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way is to use Jobs. Jobs guarantee sequential execution when you put them in sequence unlike a transformation calling multiple transformations through transformation executor (where it goes in parallel)

Create a wrapper job with `Start -> (transformation step) KTR1 -> (transformation step) KTR2 -> (transformation step) KTR3 -> Success` and run this job.

Answer (score 0):

Create a job. Drag three "Transformation" steps in that job. Check this out:

[image]

You can add as many transformations you want in a job. When you will run this job, it will execute the transformations one by one.

Comment: Thanks, Nikhil! It helps!

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer correct if it helped you. :)